# What will cause Modifier 'abstract' not allowed here in RoomDatabase file using Android Studio?

Tags: android, database, syntax-error, dao, abstract

I am learning to use Android Studio and am generally following an on-line tutorial to develop a simple app that uses the Room etc architecture for database access and management.  I have written the Entity and Dao files but in the database file, the reference to the Dao file gives a warning "Modifier 'abstract' not allowed here".  I am not sure whether this is something that will 'fix' itself later as the project develops but there was no mention of anything like this in the tutorial.

I have tried deleting and regenerating files, resyncing and cross checking line for line against comparable working code.  Google searching has produced no really comparable conditions for comparison.

```
package org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Scoring.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class ScoringDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static ScoringDatabase instance;

    public abstract ScoringDao scoringDao;

    public static synchronized ScoringDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
            ScoringDatabase.class, "scoring_database")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }


}
```

The code is the entire database definition file and the offending line of code is the one 'public abstract ScoringDao etc

Comment: You can't have abstract fields.

Answer (score 15):

I feel like a complete dork - The problem was missing parentheses.

Should have been - `public abstract ScoringDao scoringDao();`

Comment: You're not alone :)

Comment: Thank goodness this fix was so easy to find!

Comment: We've all found ourselves here one way or another.

Comment: Landed here in 2023 due to same reason. You are not alone :)